# Auto detach after auto connecting in irssi

Tags: linux, putty, raspberry-pi, irc, irssi

I have irssi auto connect to a channel and send a message to auto connect which works. But for some reason the detach command (ctrl-a + d) does not detach the screen anymore. Is there a setting for this or is there a way to auto detach the screen on startup?

Comment: Like this "HOWTO Start a detatched process as a specific user, in screen, on boot" - https://fak3r.com/2011/04/25/howto-start-a-detached-process-in-screen-on-boot/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can remotely detach a screen (from outside the screen) with `screen -d`